# Checking if word present in dictionary through for loop

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

Trying to create a dictionary with word counts from a .txt file within a `for loop`

```
def countWords(filename):
    wordlist = {} 
    infile = open(filename)

    for line in infile:
        for word in line.split():
            if str(word) in wordlist == True :
                wordlist[word] += 1
                print("old found word")
            else:
                wordlist[word] = 1 
                print(" NOT found old word")
    return wordlist
```

I expect this function to create output the word list with words listed along with their count throughout the text file. instead the loop constantly prints "NOT found old word" and outputs the wordlist dictionary will all words listed but their counts are all = 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you don't have to write `str(word) in wordlist == True`, `str(word) in wordlist` would be enough.
Second, there is no need in converting word from file to `str` class.
Third, it is good practice to use `with` operator when you open the file, in order to prevent some memory leaks, so it would be

```py
with open(filename) as infile:
    #your_code
```

Fourth, if `print` lines are not necessary, it would be more `pythonic` to write something like this:

```py
from collections import Counter

text = """Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, 
    sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore 
    magna aliquam erat volutpat"""
wordline = dict(Counter(text.split())
```

Good luck with your task!

Answer (score 1):

The line

`if str(word) in wordlist == True :`

is evaluated as follows:

first, the assertion `wordlist == True` is evaluated and returns `False`.
This leads to the expression
`if str(word) in False :`
Which is also `False`.

Therefore, the `else:` statement is triggered.

To fix it, you can either leave out the `== True`:

`if str(word) in wordlist:`

or use parentheses:

`if (str(word) in wordlist) == True :`

Although the latter one makes little sense.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your desired result, I would change the checking of key in the dictionary to

```
if str(word) in wordlist:
```

giving you the function below.

```
def countWords(filename):
    wordlist = {}
    infile = open(filename)

    for line in infile:
        for word in line.split():
            if str(word) in wordlist:
                wordlist[word] += 1
                print("old found word")
            else:
                wordlist[word] = 1
                print(" NOT found old word")
    return wordlist
```